# jQuery - simulate hover event every 'x' seconds

Tags: jquery, hover

I have 4 boxes, first one as featured box, the content will copied to that featured box once hover on other 3 boxes.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/IbrahimAboSeada/bXx5j/1/)

**html:**

```
<ul class="items clearfix">
    <li class="item">
        <a href=""><h2 class="title">01 - Lorem ipsum</h2></a>
        <p class="description">
            First item - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/42bdc2/FFFFFF&amp;text=News" alt="">
    </li><!-- Featured Item -->

    <li class="item">
        <a href=""><h2 class="title">01 - Lorem ipsum</h2></a>
        <p class="description">
            First item - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/42bdc2/FFFFFF&amp;text=News" alt="">
    </li><!-- End Item -->

    <li class="item">
        <a href=""><h2 class="title">02 - Lorem ipsum</h2></a>
        <p class="description">
            Second item - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/42bdc2/FFFFFF&amp;text=News" alt="">
    </li><!-- End Item -->

    <li class="item">
        <a href=""><h2 class="title">03 - Lorem ipsum</h2></a>
        <p class="description">
            Third item - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/42bdc2/FFFFFF&amp;text=News" alt="">
    </li><!-- End Item -->
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var feat =$(".item").first();
var item =$(".item").next();
item.mouseover(function(){
    featitem = $(this).html();
    feat.html(featitem);
    $(this).addClass("featured");
});
```

basically i need to simulate this hover event every 'x' seconds, otherwise i need the content for each 3 boxes to copy to featured box automatically without hover and keep hover event work as well.

Comment: Your usage of `next()` does not make sense?  Why trigger a hover event rather than simply change the content on a schedule? Do you need to rotate amongst the `items`?  Why not have a different class/id for the element into which the featured content is being inserted to distinguish it from the other content elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
var speed = 5000;

(function fn() {
    $.each(item, function(i,el) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(el).trigger('mouseover');
        }, i * speed);
    });
    setTimeout(fn, item.length * speed );
})();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bXx5j/5/)

Comment: 5 seconds === 5000 milliseconds

Comment: see [link](http://jsfiddle.net/IbrahimAboSeada/bXx5j/4/) not jumping after 5 seconds.

Comment: @IbrahimAboSeada - changed it a little bit, see if that works.